# Is there a name for this theorem?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, inequalities

I wonder if there is a name or reference for the following fact. It is not the proof I am looking for.

Let $s_1, s_2, ...,s_n$ be non-negative real numbers ordered in a non-increasing way. Let $b_1,b_2,...,b_n$ be non-negative real numbers ordered in a non-decreasing way (so opposite of the $s_i$).

Then the average value $$\frac{s_1+s_2+\cdots +s_n}{n}$$ is at least as large as the
weighted average $$\frac{b_1 s_1+\cdots+b_n s_n}{b_1+\cdots+b_n}.$$

Thanks!

Comment: [Chebyshev's sum inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality)

Comment: Please use TeX on this site.

Comment: I thought it looked like the "Rearrangement Inequality"
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality);
it's not quite, but the inequality here can be recovered from it by
averaging over all $n!$ rearrangements.  (The Wikipedia page notes that
Chebyshev's sum inequality is a consequence of Rearrangement.)

Answer (score 19):

This is known as [Chebyshev's Sum Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality). (I've only ever seen it used in the context of competition math, but Wikipedia gives a reference to Hardy-Littlewood-Polya.)

Comment: I've seen it used at least once by K. Matomäki (in "On signs of Fourier coefficients of cusp forms", Math. Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. 152 (2012), no. 2, 207–222, if I remember correctly).

Answer (score 4):

It is called often called "Chebyshev's other inequality". And this makes more sense than the name "Chebyshev's sum inequality" proposed by Wikipedia, since even Wikepedia knows that there is a version for integrals.

Comment: Integrals aren’t sums?

Comment: So one of my physics teachers told us. But I could understand it only after a transposition.

Comment: @LutzMattner : ... so integrals are permutations of sums?  :-)